# Cannot Import OrbitControls using Node 12 ES6 Import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, three.js, es6-module-loader

I'm Using Node 12 (experimental-modules) and three (npm) and i cant get Imports to work for OrbitControls.js. I have index.js as "script: module".

Neither of these ES6 imports work

I tried copying the OrbitControls.js file out of the js folder (from the root folder of three) and placing it adjacent to index.js then adding

```
import {OrbitControls} from "./OrbitControls.js"
```

It did not work i receive the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './OrbitControls.js' does
>   not provide an export named 'OrbitControls'

So I also tried to use the three library

```
import {OrbitControls} from "/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
```

returns 404 error, so i tried relative imports

```
import {OrbitControls} from "../../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
```

got the 404 error again.

Ive also tried (something another user reccommended) const OrbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls but the error seems happen from the ES6 import alone.

Comment: JSM is not the same as ESM https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used experimental-modules, but your second example should read

`import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";`

without the `/` before `three`;

If that doesn't work, you could try copy-pasting the OrbitControls.js source code [from here](https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js) to your own folder.

`import { OrbitControls } from "./myFolder/OrbitControls";`

If this works, then it might be a problem with your `node_modules` installation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second answer gives me the error "Failed to resolve module specifier Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." i dont know why though.

Comment: I've tried copying the OrbitControls file from the jsm folder and posting it next to index.js and the problem is that OrbitControls file is full of relative imports to other js files "from "../../../build/three.module.js"" so it gives an error on line 18. I'll try and reload node_modules

Comment: Ive just reinstalled node_modules unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Ive updated to Node 14.3 to see if it was the experimetnal features but to no avail.

Comment: I've just tried to import three using import * as THREE from 'three' and It says "Failed to resolve module specifier Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." so I think this is a general problem with three?